# streamwriter writing duplicate lines to file

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, streamwriter

I'm stumped. I have a data from 3 datatables being written to a text file but when i'm writing a certain table to the file it's writing duplicates and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code for writing to the file

```
        public void writeCharge2(StreamWriter sw, string dos1, int i)
    {
        getCharges(dos1, SqlCon);
        foreach (DataRow row in chargeTable.Rows)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n <= chargeTable.Rows.Count -1; n++)
            {                    
                ChargeLine = chargeTable.Rows[n][0].ToString();

                writeCharge(sw, dos1, i, ChargeLine);
                sw.WriteLine();
                payChart.Reset();
                payGraph.Reset();
            }

        }
        chargeTable.Reset();
    }

    public void writeCharge(StreamWriter sw, string dos2, int i, string CPTLine)
    {
        getPayments(ChargeLine, SqlCon, dos2);
        string description = getDesc(CPTLine, SqlCon);
        sw.WriteLine("   Description: " + CPTLine + " - " + description);
        sw.WriteLine("-----------Payments-----------");

        if (i < payGraph.Rows.Count)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in payGraph.Rows)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length -1; i++)
                {
                    DateTime payDate = Convert.ToDateTime(payGraph.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                    string payDate1 = payDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    decimal money = Convert.ToDecimal(payGraph.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                    string money1 = money.ToString("C");
                    string payer = payGraph.Rows[i][2].ToString();

                    sw.Write("Payment Date: " + payDate1 + " | ");
                    sw.Write("Amount: " + money1 + " | ");
                    sw.Write("Payer: " + payer);
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }

                sw.WriteLine();
            }
        }

    }

        public void writeData(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        clearTables();
        getDos(SqlCon);
        int i = 0;

        foreach(DataRow row in servicetable.Rows)
        {
            string dosNow = Convert.ToString(servicetable.Rows[i][0]);

            setupPat(sw, i);
            writeCharge2(sw, dosNow, i);
            sw.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                i++;

        }
```

Here is how it's being written to the file which you can see the duplicate lines being written

Date of Service: 08/22/2012
   Description: 76775 - US RETROPERITONEAL LIMITED
-----------Payments-----------
Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $23.14 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $5.78 | Payer: Insurance

Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $23.14 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $5.78 | Payer: Insurance


   Description: 93922 - EXTREMITY NON-INVASIVE 1 OR 2 LEVELS
-----------Payments-----------
Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $9.74 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $2.43 | Payer: Insurance

Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $9.74 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $2.43 | Payer: Insurance


   Description: 76775 - US RETROPERITONEAL LIMITED
-----------Payments-----------
Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $23.14 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $5.78 | Payer: Insurance

Payment Date: 09/10/2012 | Amount: $23.14 | Payer: Insurance
Payment Date: 09/24/2012 | Amount: $5.78 | Payer: Insurance

Comment: Remove this line **for (i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length -1; i++)** AND use **row** instead of **payGraph.Rows[i]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `foreach` loop is not necessary within the writeCharge2 function. You iterate rows using `foreach` and then in each iteration print all the rows, so for 2 rows they will be printed twice, for 3 rows - 3 times etc.